# Jquery-confirm return to parent Modal on nested confirms

Tags: jquery

I use jquery-confirm plugin.

I'm looking for a way to insert a double confirm, and `IF CONFIRM 2 IS NOT CONFIRMED`, return again to modal `CONFIRM 1`:

From official doc I don't see any example of this case.

```
         $.confirm({
            title: 'CONFIRM 1',
            content: 'Are you sure? I final confirm will appear',
            buttons: {
                ok: {
                text: 'CONFIRM',
                action: function () {

                      $.confirm({
                            title: 'CONFIRM 2',
                            content: 'Are you REALLY sure?',
                            buttons: {
                                ok: {
                                    text: 'FINAL CONFIRM',
                                    action: function () {

                                    }
                                },
                                cancel: {
                                    text: 'Cancel',
                                    action: function () {
                                        // i want to return to CONFIRM 1 MODAL
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                      }
                },
                cancel: {
                                    text: 'Cancel',
                                    action: function () {

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: So what is wrong with nested confirm shown?

Comment: @charlietfl i've already found solution thanks

Comment: Classic example of confusing the users of the page with nested dialogs!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
    var modal = $.confirm({
        title: 'CONFIRM 1',
        content: 'Are you sure? I final confirm will appear',
        buttons: {
            ok: {
            text: 'CONFIRM',
            action: function () {

                  $.confirm({
                        title: 'CONFIRM 2',
                        content: 'Are you REALLY sure?',
                        buttons: {
                            ok: {
                                text: 'FINAL CONFIRM',
                                action: function () {

                                }
                            },
                            cancel: {
                                text: 'Cancel',
                                action: function () {

                                      modal.open();


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                  }
            },
            cancel: {
                                text: 'Cancel',
                                action: function () {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```